How can I debug a test in ut_runner under VS Code without running it to completion first?
If a unit test has not yet been run to completion in ut_runner in VS Code, then when you try to debug it, ut_runner will automatically run it to completion first.  Is there a way to tell ut_runner not to do that?
I have a unit test that gets into an infinite loop somewhere.  It's a very complicated test, and its hard to follow the code.  I would like to run it in debug mode and step into the code to find where it is stopping.  But since I have to run it to completion first and it never completes, I can't use the debugger!
